# Is every piece of music a "track"?

Tags: terminology

Coming from the [question about distinguishing *songs* from *tracks* based on presence of vocals](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/26/47), I wonder if *track* is a term that can be used for *every* kind of musical work?

In the comments, [Noach mi Frankfurt](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/users/62/noach-mi-frankfurt) [thinks](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/26/is-it-ok-to-distinguish-songs-from-tracks-based-on-presence-of-vocals/29#comment21_26) that a track has to be recorded on a medium, while [Unihedro](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/users/26/unihedro) [thinks](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/26/is-it-ok-to-distinguish-songs-from-tracks-based-on-presence-of-vocals/29#comment23_26) that the definition of the term has changed.

So, how do we define *track*?

Comment: Some pieces of music are performed live and never recorded.

Answer (score 7):

Most literally, a 'track' is a section of a medium (tape, wax, vinyl) on which a physical (or magnetic) track has been created due to a recording being made or pressed there. Even during times when audio usually did correspond to a physical track, when people said 'track' they were often talking about *the song/piece of audio*, rather than the physical track.

Now that many media (e.g. mp3 files) don't have a physical track, the word 'track' seems to mean *a recording of the type that would have been a track on a record (or other medium)*. So a two second mp3 file of someone laughing isn't a 'track' unless it has actually come from a sequence of other sound files arranged like an album; A song can usually be called a 'track', because we are used to songs being tracks on albums.

Comment: I agree here.  I am a musician who records on a frequent basis, and someone who listens to a lot of music.  Using this term to describe the discrete units on an album is slang.  Another way to think of the appropriate way to use this term, think of a 4-track recorder.  With this device, you can record 4 separate tracks of the same song, and mix their levels to attain the optimum sound.

Answer (score 4):

According to the definition a 'track' (when referring to music) is

> one of several songs or pieces of music on a CD or other musical recording:

or

> a part of a magnetic strip onto which sound can be recorded, with several tracks on one magnetic strip: *When a piece of music is recorded, each instrument is recorded separately on a 24 or 48–track tape.*

[Definition of track](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/track)

So a song is a song whether live, sheet music, cd, tape, vinyl.
But a track is a song or piece of music when recorded onto a physical medium.

Comment: I think your second definition refers to each recording on the tape, not to the tape. "Each instrument is recorded separately on a 24 or 48 track tape" -> Each instrument is it's own track. Each *tape* has multiple *tracks*, so a tape is a collection of tracks, rather than just one.

Comment: Maybe the 'or' should be an 'and'. It's one of those definitions that mean one thing to the general public and another to the professionals involved in the recording industry.